# How to convert and display an Integer into YYYYMMDD format using Select query without neglecting days and leap year logic?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, oracle, plsql

I have a query to retrieve a set of non null records from a column x consisting of DATE format.

> If count(x) = 35 then i need to display the value as 1 Month & 5 days
>
> If 369 days then 1 year & 4 days or If 400 days then 1 year 1 month 5 days respectively

**Query: In the above instance,unfortunately i am neglecting 0.25 days but How to tweak my actual requirement in such a way that i don't end up neglecting days and handle leap year logic too**

*How to solve this issue?*

Comment: You'll need a starting date since not all month have the same number of days.

Comment: Months have not always 30 days. So 35  is April 30 days and 5 days of May or 28 days of february and 7 days of march? (by the way 30 * 12 are 360 days and this is not an year)

Comment: If we pretend that every month has 30 days, wouldn't 400 days be 1 year (365 days), 1 month (30 days), and 5 days (365 + 30 + 5 = 400) rather than 10 days?

Comment: Just for future reference, you could have been a lot clearer in your question.  The first line is not at all helpful.  Really you wanted to know how to convert an integer into a number of years, months, days.  It seems  you were happy to assume 1 year = 365.25 days - you should also have stated that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found something that will suit my requirement.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2587161?start=0&tstart=0

```
   select days,
   floor(days / 365.25) years,
   floor(mod(days,365.25) / (365.25 / 12)) months,
   round(mod(days,365.25 / 12)) days
   from periods
```

So this can produce expected output when number is given. This produces output as years,months and remaining days

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear if you need of a time's generic computing in years, months and days, based on averages of number of days of a month, etc.. or if you want an exact  compute of the number of the months that pass starting froma adate.. for example if your total sum of 400 days start from 15 march, then the month is counted by 1 after, let's say, 15 days, and so  the remaining days are 20.. I don't know if I explained..

In the first hypotesis, you may use the following pseudo-coded solution, that is a very approximative method..

however, if you know a start date, it is possible to compute exactly how many "bissextile" days are comprehended between your interval of days starting from your start date

let's say to have output variables Years, Months, Days .. and an input totalDaysdays assigned with your data retrieved from the db, then:

```
(pseudocode)

Years = trunc((totalDays / 365) 

bissextileDays = trunc((totalDays / 365) / 4)

numDaysOffset  = (totalDays Mod  365) + bissextileDays 

Months = trunc(numDaysOffset / 30)
Days = numDaysOffset Mod 30
```